# Combinatorics problems

Tags: combinatorics

1) The sports club in the youth group consists of $12$ people, including $4$ girls. How many ways to choose a team of $5$ people, $3$ boys and $2$ girls?

2) How many different three-digit odd numbers can be formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ provided that the numbers are not repeated?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the two problems? What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: 56*6 = 336 for first problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1)$ How many ways can you choose $3$ boys from a group of $12-4=8$ boys? How many way can you choose $2$ girls from a group of $4$ girls? Multiply them by *fundamental principle of counting* and you get $\binom{8}{3} \times \binom{4}{2}=56 \times 6=336.$

$(2)$ The last digit can be $1$ or $3$. If it is $1$, we can choose any two from $0,2,3,4$ to fill up the first two places (since we cannot use $1$ again, as numbers can't be repeated). Note that here the order is important. So there are $4 \times 3=12$ ways to do it. Similarly if we have $3$ as the last digit, there are $12$ ways to do it. In total, you have $24$ odd numbers. But there's one more pitfall as noticed by @MeesdeVries. We cannot count the numbers starting with $0$. So we have to deduct $6$ numbers: $021, 031, 041, 013, 023, 043$ from the earlier set. So the total number of three-digited odd numbers obtained in the process is $24-6=18$. Thanks @MeesdeVries for the correction.

Comment: Arguably, 023 should not count as a three-digit number. So depending on what exactly three-digit number means you might want to adapt the answer to the second part to your needs.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: You're right! I'm correcting it.. thanks for the help! My bad!

Comment: @amWhy: I got your point. Thanks.